# Transform a path of nodes into a tree structure list of lists

Tags: r, tree

I have a data.frame with one column representing a path of nodes, which I would like to transform to a tree. I there any simple function to do so ?

Here's a simple example:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "A1", "A2", "A1a", "A1b", "A2a", "A2b", "A2c"),
  Path = c("1", "1,1", "1,2", "1,1,1", "1,1,2", "1,2,1", "1,2,2", "1,2,3")
)
```

Which I would like to transform to :

```
nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "A",
    li_attr = list(id = "1")
    state = list(opened = TRUE),
    
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "A1",
        li_attr = list(id = "1,1")
        state = list(opened = TRUE),
        
        children = list(
          list(
            text = "A1a",
            li_attr = list(id = "1,1,1")),
          list(
            text = "A1b",
            li_attr = list(id = "1,1,2"))
          )),

        list(
            text = "A2",
            li_attr = list(id = "1,2")
            state = list(opened = TRUE),
            
            children = list(
              list(
                text = "A2a",
                li_attr = list(id = "1,2,1")),
              list(
                text = "A2b",
                li_attr = list(id = "1,2,2")),
              list(
                text = "A2c",
                li_attr = list(id = "1,2,3"))
            
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package **{[data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)}** is helpful for working with hierarchical data structures. In your case:

- add a `pathString` to your data frame (a slash-separated string like a directory path, where the last letter of your variable *name* corresponds to the endpoint, and each preceding letter to an upstream folder; finally convert the dataframe to a tree, using `as.Node`:

```
library(data.tree)
library(dplyr)

the_treedata <- 
    data |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(pathString = strsplit(Name, '') |> unlist() |> paste(collapse = '/'))
```

```
## > the_treedata
## # A tibble: 8 x 3
## # Rowwise: 
##   Name  Path  pathString
##   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
## 1 A     1     A         
## 2 A1    1,1   A/1       
## 3 A2    1,2   A/2       
## 4 A1a   1,1,1 A/1/a     
## 5 A1b   1,1,2 A/1/b
```

- convert to a data tree:

```
my_tree <- my_treedata |> as.Node()
```

- traverse the tree and `Get` the result of applying a custom function to each node as a list:

```
the_list <- 
    the_tree$Get(\(node) list(text = node$name,
                              li_attr = list(node$Path),
                              state = list(opened = TRUE),
                              children = Map(node$children,
                                             f = \(child) list(text = child$Name,
                                                               state = list(opened = TRUE),
                                                               li_attr = list(id = node$Path)
                                                               )
                                             )
                              ),
                 filterFun = \(node) !is.leaf(node), ## leave nodes already captured via the `children` attribute of their parent nodes
                 simplify = FALSE
                 )
```

Comment: I have an issue when having such data ```data <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "A1", "A2", "A1a", "A1b", "A2a", "A2b", "A2c", "B"), Path = c("1", "1,a", "1,b", "1,a,1", "1,a,2", "1,b,1", "1,b,2", "1,b,3", "2")).``` Here, "1,a" et "1,b" are associated with parent "2", while it should be parent "1". Do you know any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing function that does exactly what you want. You would have to write a recursive function to do it for you:

```r
f <- function(path, name, parent_node = NULL) {
  nodes <- strsplit(path, ',')
  parents <- match(unique(sapply(nodes, `[`, 1)), path)
  lapply(parents, function(i) {
    li <- list(Text = name[i],
         li_attr = list(id = if(is.null(parent_node)) parents[i]
                          else paste(parent_node, parents[i], sep = ',')))
    kids <- sapply(nodes, \(x) x[1] == parents[i])
    if(length(kids) > 0) {
      if(sum(kids) > 1) {
        li$opened = TRUE
        n <- which(kids & lengths(nodes) > 1)
        li$children <-
        f(sapply(nodes[n], \(x) paste0(x[-1], collapse = ',')), name[n],
          parent_node = li$li_attr$id)
      }
    }
    return(li)
  })
}
```

We call it like this:

```r
result <- f(data$Path, data$Name)
```

And the result looks like this:

```r
list(
  list(Text = "A", 
       li_attr = list(id = 1L), 
       opened = TRUE, 
       children = list(
         list(Text = "A1", 
              li_attr = list(id = "1,1"), 
              opened = TRUE, 
              children = list(
                list(Text = "A1a", 
                     li_attr = list(id = "1,1,1")), 
                list(Text = "A1b", 
                     li_attr = list(id = "1,1,2"))
                )
              ), 
         list(Text = "A2", 
              li_attr = list(id = "1,2"), 
              opened = TRUE, 
              children = list(
                list(Text = "A2a", 
                     li_attr = list(id = "1,2,1")), 
                list(Text = "A2b", 
                     li_attr = list(id = "1,2,2")), 
                list(Text = "A2c", 
                     li_attr = list(id = "1,2,3"))
                )
              )
         )
       )
  )
```

This looks like a typical structure for JSON, in which case you can convert it to JSON using `jsonlite::toJSON(result)`, which yields:

```json
[
  {
    "Text": ["A"],
    "li_attr": {"id": [1]},
    "opened": [true],
    "children": [
      {
        "Text": ["A1"],
        "li_attr": {
          "id": ["1,1"]
        },
        "opened": [true],
        "children": [
          {
            "Text": ["A1a"],
            "li_attr": {"id": ["1,1,1"]}
          },
          {
            "Text": ["A1b"],
            "li_attr": {"id": ["1,1,2"]}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Text": ["A2"],
        "li_attr": {"id": ["1,2"]},
        "opened": [true],
        "children": [
          {
            "Text": ["A2a"],
            "li_attr": {"id": ["1,2,1"]}
          },
          {
            "Text": ["A2b"],
            "li_attr": {"id": ["1,2,2"]
            }
          },
          {
            "Text": ["A2c"],
            "li_attr": {"id": ["1,2,3"]}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```